# Exchange two children of a parent rule in antlr4

Tags: antlr4

I have a rule like below

```
  parent_clause: first_clause second_clause
         | second_clause first_clause
         ;
```

how can I interchange the children so that I can always have `first_clause` followed by `second_clause`?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I interchange the children so that I can always have `first_clause` followed by `second_clause`

There is no such functionality in ANTLR4.

ANTLR4 provides visitor- and listener classes that helps you build your own parse/abstract syntax tree from your input. That is the place where you can rewrite your tree.

Here is a blog from Terence (author of ANTLR) in which he explains why there is no support for tree rewriting: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/~admin/blog/2012/12/08/524353/Tree+rewriting+in+ANTLR+v4